# WSO2 IS Default OTP 2nd factor in my account

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I need that when a user log in wso2 is my account portal, by default, the second authentication factor based on OTP is enabled.

I have tried to modify it in the management console but it is not allowed. How can I modify the default configuration of myaccount in WSO2 IS 5.11?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Myaccount and Console are read-only system apps. Remove `Myaccount` from read-only system apps by adding the following to the `deployment.toml` at `<wso2is-home>/repository/conf/deployment.toml` location. (This config makes that only console is read-only)

```
[system_applications]
read_only_apps = ["Console"]
```

If you want to remove Myaccount and Console apps both out of the readonly apps, use the following.

```
 [system_applications]
 read_only_apps = []
```

Then restart the server. You will be able to do configuration changes now.
Refer: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/setup/migrating-what-has-changed/#configurable-system-apps